# Wifi disconnects after a while and does not restart

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad machine my wifi connection becomes unavailable after a random amount of time (sometimes it takes only 5-10 minutes after restarting the computer, whereas on other occasions wifi runs for several hours without any issues).

I ran `journalctl --follow` and got the following:

```
dic 10 08:54:55 user systemd[2142]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
dic 10 08:54:55 user dbus-daemon[2171]: [session uid=1000 pid=2171] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
dic 10 08:54:55 user systemd[2142]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
dic 10 08:56:07 user systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs...
dic 10 08:56:07 user systemd[1]: Started Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
dic 10 09:01:10 user rtkit-daemon[1796]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
dic 10 09:01:10 user rtkit-daemon[1796]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
dic 10 09:04:31 user systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
dic 10 09:04:31 user anacron[4963]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-12-10
dic 10 09:04:31 user anacron[4963]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
dic 10 09:06:23 user systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
dic 10 09:06:23 user systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
dic 10 09:11:58 user NetworkManager[1362]: <info>  [1639138318.3459] connectivity: (wlp3s0) timed out
dic 10 09:11:58 user NetworkManager[1362]: <info>  [1639138318.3460] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
dic 10 09:11:58 user dbus-daemon[1318]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1362 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
dic 10 09:11:58 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:11:58] offline
dic 10 09:11:58 user systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
dic 10 09:11:58 user dbus-daemon[1318]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
dic 10 09:11:58 user systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
dic 10 09:11:58 user nm-dispatcher[5259]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
dic 10 09:11:58 user nm-dispatcher[5259]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
dic 10 09:16:28 user NetworkManager[1362]: <info>  [1639138588.6719] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
dic 10 09:16:28 user dbus-daemon[1318]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1362 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
dic 10 09:16:28 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:16:28] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
dic 10 09:16:28 user systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
dic 10 09:16:28 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:16:28] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
dic 10 09:16:28 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:16:28] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
dic 10 09:16:28 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:16:28] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
dic 10 09:16:28 user dbus-daemon[1318]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
dic 10 09:16:28 user systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
dic 10 09:16:28 user nm-dispatcher[5442]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
dic 10 09:16:28 user nm-dispatcher[5442]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
dic 10 09:16:30 user whoopsie[1976]: [09:16:30] online
dic 10 09:17:01 user CRON[5465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
dic 10 09:17:01 user CRON[5466]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
dic 10 09:17:01 user CRON[5465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
dic 10 09:19:30 user systemd-resolved[1255]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 200.30.192.15.
dic 10 09:20:36 user systemd-resolved[1255]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 200.83.1.4.
dic 10 09:26:38 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:38 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:38 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:38 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:44 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:44 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:44 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:44 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: 08b28086 00100000 028000bb 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c2708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003141 00002000 00000014 40000001
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f b2800460 00000000
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.1) config registers:
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000000: 8c128086 00100007 060400d4 00810010 00000000 00000000 00030300 200000f0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.1: 00000020: b280b280 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 000002ff
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: Timeout waiting for hardware access (CSR_GP_CNTRL 0xffffffff)
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 0 at /build/linux-pzGUHO/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1985 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: Modules linked in: isofs rfcomm ccm acpi_call(OE) msr nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) cmac bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev media btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal arc4 intel_powerclamp kvm wmi_bmof irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd iwlmvm mac80211 intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_intel thinkpad_acpi iwlwifi snd_hda_codec joydev snd_rawmidi nvram intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_core input_leds snd_hwdep snd_seq mei_me snd_pcm snd_seq_device serio_raw cfg80211 mei lpc_ich
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  snd_timer snd soundcore shpchp mac_hid wmi sch_fq_codel coretemp bbswitch(OE) parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 mmc_block i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops e1000e psmouse ahci drm sdhci_pci libahci ptp sdhci ipmi_devintf pps_core ipmi_msghandler video [last unloaded: nvidia]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: P        W  OE    4.15.0-163-generic #171-Ubuntu
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20EFCTO1WW/20EFCTO1WW, BIOS GNET73WW (2.21 ) 03/12/2015
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff91d1be2c3dc8 EFLAGS: 00010086
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff91d1989a0018 RCX: 0000000000000006
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff91d1be2d64d0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RBP: ffff91d1be2c3de0 R08: 0000000000000522 R09: 0000000000000004
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: R10: ffffe7b5da752280 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff91d1989a8f00
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: R13: ffff91d1be2c3df0 R14: 000000000000000a R15: ffff91d1989a0018
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff91d1be2c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: CR2: 00007f0747779008 CR3: 000000024800a006 CR4: 00000000001606e0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: Call Trace:
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  <IRQ>
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  iwl_read_prph+0x38/0x90 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  iwl_trans_pcie_log_scd_error+0x125/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  ? iwl_pcie_txq_build_tfd+0xe0/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x46/0x70 [iwlwifi]
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  call_timer_fn+0x30/0x130
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  run_timer_softirq+0x3f3/0x430
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x43/0xb0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x2c/0x40
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  __do_softirq+0xe4/0x2d4
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  irq_exit+0xc5/0xd0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x79/0x140
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  apic_timer_interrupt+0x90/0xa0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  </IRQ>
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x2f0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb0e8431d7e68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RAX: ffff91d1be2e1940 RBX: 000001ef6f3b3027 RCX: 000000000000001f
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RDX: 000001ef6f3b3027 RSI: fffffffb8b415bcb RDI: 0000000000000000
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: RBP: ffffb0e8431d7ea8 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 0000000000021180
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: R10: ffffb0e8431d7e38 R11: 0000066dd6460a20 R12: ffff91d1be2eb900
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: R13: 0000000000000003 R14: ffffffff8a173298 R15: 0000000000000000
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x97/0x2f0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  do_idle+0x18c/0x1f0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  start_secondary+0x1ab/0x200
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel:  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: Code: 00 00 e8 7a 2e b1 c7 eb 9d 48 89 df be 24 00 00 00 c6 05 1b 7d 02 00 01 e8 b4 e6 fe ff 48 c7 c7 00 15 ac c1 89 c6 e8 e6 ee 1e c7 <0f> 0b eb bb 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 49 c7 c0 40 15 ac c1 48 c7 
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: ---[ end trace 791c2845a0bfe50f ]---
dic 10 09:26:47 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [73, 86] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
dic 10 09:26:50 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:50 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:50 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:50 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:56 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:56 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:26:56 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:26:56 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:27:02 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:27:02 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
dic 10 09:27:02 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
dic 10 09:27:02 user kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem permanently would be very much appreciated!